# calculations in BigQuery returns E-4 SQL

Tags: sql, math, google-bigquery, calculated-columns

I need to perform simple calculations in BigQuery and save the result in a new column. Below is my code:

```
SELECT id, 
CPM, 
(1 / 1000000000 * CPM) AS Revenue
FROM `big_query_table`
```

For some numbers, it does the calculations right, but for other numbers, it is not even a number that is being returned. Here is the output:

[image]

The last number `930000` should have returned `0.00093`

Comment: The last number *is* 0.00093.  That is what `E-4` does.

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but then my SUM in the separate query gives me the wrong result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below instead (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
SELECT id, 
CPM, 
CAST(1 / 1000000000 * CPM as numeric) AS Revenue
FROM `big_query_table`
```

this will output below

[image]

Comment: Perfect! That works, I have accepted the answer and upvoted it.